# Что работает быстрее: массив или ArrayList?

Tags: java

Что работает быстрее? Прогнал тест 100 раз. Результаты всегда разные: то один быстрее, то второй. Так есть ли реальный выигрыш в использовании массива вместо ArrayList? ArrayList создавал с нужным размером сразу, чтобы время на "расширение" не тратилось.

Проверялось быстродействие команды add. Пытался понять, уменьшит ли замена ArrayList на обычный массив в "узких местах" время выполнения (часто слышал такое предположение). Если в моем случае всегда известен заранее размер массива/листа. Результаты получились случайные. Иногда ArrayList значительно быстрее, иногда массив, иногда они равны.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
  private static int COUNT = 1000000;

  private static double getPeriod(Runnable r) {
    System.gc();
    Date date = new Date();
    r.run();
    return (new Date().getTime() - date.getTime());
  }

  private static void testList(final List list) {
    double period = getPeriod(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
          list.add(new Object());
        }
      }
    });
    System.out.println("List " + period);
  }

  private static void testArray(final Object[] array) {
    double period = getPeriod(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
          array[i] = new Object();
        }
      }
    });
    System.out.println("Array " + period);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      List arrayList = new ArrayList(COUNT);
      Object[] array = new Object[COUNT];

      testList(arrayList);
      testArray(array);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: А если увеличить размеры данных, чтобы тесты сделать точнее, изменять типы данных пробовали?

Comment: Прошу прощение, влезу с нубским вопросом: array list - это что то типа массива на связанных списках?

Comment: На связанных списках - это LinkedList. А ArrayList - динамический массив. Предполагается, что обычный массив должен работать значительно быстрее, чем array list.

Comment: Добавьте код которым тестировали, и результаты тестирования. Тогда будем думать, в чем не так построения теста (результат должен быть один и тот же)

Comment: Нестабильность результатов тестирования обычно означает, что тест плохо написан.

Comment: Вопрос сформулирован некорректно. Производительность ЧЕГО вы измеряли? Свертки, отображения, поиска, вставки в начало/конец/середину, расширения, фильтрации, чего-то еще? Структуры данных "не работают", как вы выразились: работают конкретные алгоритмы на структурах данных. Уточните, скорость какой операции или их комбинации приминительно к структуре ArrayList вас интересует, тогда и будут ответы.

Comment: Как я и говорил: ваш тест ничего не измеряет, вот и результат никакой.

Comment: В чем ошибка?

Comment: Всё дело в том, что при написании теста надо сводить выполнение постороннего кода к минимуму. А во-вторых, надо стараться, чтобы время выполнения теста было больше погрешностей, вызванных временными эффектами (сборка мусора, тупняк глупой винды или ещё какая-нибудь еруна). Посмотрите мой тест, например.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Обычный массив почти наверняка будет выигрывать в скорости как при доступе, так и при записи. Хотя бы потому, что при обращении к ArrayList у вас лишний вызов метода, а может и не один. С другой стороны, внутри ArrayList'а тот же самый массив и доступ вполняется по тому же принципу, поэтому если нет чрезмерной нагрузки на него, то в общем их производительность примерно одного порядка.

Разница для вас в том, что с листами работать намного проще и удобнее, чем с массивами. По этой причине вам не следует заниматься ерундой и гонять какие-то нелепые тесты, а просто использовать ArrayList, если только у вас нет каких-то ОЧЕНЬ серьёзных оснований использовать массив. Одно из таких оснований: вы точно знаете заранее размер массива и вы точно знаете, что использование этого массива в коде ограничено и вам не придётся городить огород, чтобы гонять потом эти массивы в листы и наоборот.

**UPD** Что за числа в вашем тесте детские? 1000.000? Это просто смешно. Я прогнал тест на выполнение 10.000.000.000 добавлений и получил вот что:

```
primitive array: 78896 ms
array list: 132532 ms
```

Второй прогон

```
primitive array: 76832 ms
array list: 124047 ms
```

Исходный код теста  [здесь](http://pastebin.mozilla-russia.org/108715) . Как видно, массив почти вдвое быстрее списка и никакой инлайнинг, рантайм-оптимизации не помогли, хотя, казалось бы, на большом интервале вркемени эти все оптимизации должны были бы сработать и время могло бы выровняться. Но нет.

**UPD2**

Убрал сборку мусора вообще и перегруппировал нули и получил следующее

```
primitive array: 26177 ms
array list: 54482 ms
```

Результат очень стабилен. Думаю, на get результаты будут подобные.

**UPD3**
Кстати, вот показательный пример для любителей вызывать руками System.gc: как видно, частая ненужная сборка мусора приводит к двухкратному снижению производительности в данном тесте.

Comment: Код красивый. Но до конца не понятно, меряется ли время именно операции вставки в структуры, т.к. время на создание вставляемого объекта не учитывается.

Comment: Какое время создания? Вставляемый объект создаётся один раз.

Comment: К сожалению, мой код имеет недостаток: помимо всего прочего я вынужден выполнять сумму и ещё всякую ерунду в цикле. В противном случае виртуальная машина через какое время обнаружит, что побочный эффект от кода отсутствует и не будет ничего выполнять.

Comment: Да, я неправильно написал насчет вставляемого объекта. Я имел в виду массив (список) в функции, которая вызывается RETRIES = 10000 раз.

Comment: Это не имеет большого значения. Идея в том, чтобы сравнить одно относительно другого. Создание массива и создания эксземпляра класса ArrayList хотя и отнимают немного времени, но разница во времени их создания не даст такой разницы, чтобы это повлияло на результат. С другой стороны, альтернатива непонятна: непонятно как можно исправить проблему.

Comment: Интересно, если вставлять COUNT раз в случайную позицию (именно вставлять, сдвигая элементы массива, если место уже занято), то результат сильно изменится ?

Comment: Сильно изменится. Будет катастрофа :) Для вставок в произвольные позиции лучше подходит LinkedList

Comment: Ага, я кажется понял. ArrayList это просто массив, который может менять свой размер, что-то вроде realloc() ? Тогда непонятно, почему скорость в полтора раза хуже, ведь размер в ходе теста не менялся. Или при его инициализации выделяется не вся запрошенная память ?

Comment: Должна быть выделена вся. Видимо, инлайнинг по какой-то причине не срабатывает, поэтому на каждый инсерт приходится по выхову метода (а может даже по два вызова), а для массива это не так. У меня сейчас нет по рукой jdk-fastdebug, так что не могу посмотреть какой машинный код там генерируется, но подозреваю, что дело именно в этом.

Comment: Такой результат можно получить на Java 6 (1.6). На ранних версиях (до оптимизаций) массив будет обгонять список в ~50 раз. Видимо, об этом автор и прочел где-то :)

Answer (score 5):

ArrayList это частный случай обычного списка в котором данные хранятся в виде массива. т.е ArrayList служит посредником между пользователем и массивом чисел предоставляя ему интерфейс List. без посредника всегда быстрее.

p.s. если вы сравниваете производительность этих классов то вам нужно задуматся о том правильно ли вы подошли к решению вашей задачи.

Answer (score 4):

В данном тесте больше времени уходит на создание новых объектов во время теста

```
array[i] = new Object();
```

или

```
list.add(new Object());
```

Думаю, погрешность именно отсюда, так как создание объекта гораздо более трудоемкая работа. 
Впрочем List, конечно, будет медленнее, ведь обращение к методу get (как и к любому другому) - это сначала обращение к таблице виртуальных методов, затем сохранение регистров в стеке и т.д. 
Лучше производить тест с заранее подготовленными данными.

Answer (score 0):

Выигрыш в использовании ArrayList в том, что без проблем можно добавлять новые элементы, в том числе и в середину листа. А в случае использования простого массива вам самому пришлось бы заново выделять память и перезаписывать элементы т.к. размер массива поменять нельзя, после того как была выделена память.

Если бы ваш тест проверял скорость добавления новых элементов в середину ArrayList и массива, то я полагаю скорость ArrayList была бы выше.

Comment: "Если бы ваш тест проверял скорость добавления новых элементов в середину ArrayList и массива, то я полагаю скорость ArrayList была бы выше." - ??? С какой стати?

Comment: "Выигрыш в использовании ArrayList в том, что без проблем можно добавлять новые элементы, в том числе и в середину листа. А в случае использования простого массива вам самому пришлось бы заново выделять память и перезаписывать элементы" - это вообще феерический бред. ArrayList внутри будет делать то же самое. Просто в случае ArrayList'а вам не пришлось бы писать этот код самим.

Comment: А если реализовать ArrayList как список с разряженным индексом ?

Comment: @cy6erGn0m, но внутри его оптимизировали скорее всего (memcpy?), а в твоём коде будет тупо цикл, да ещё и с проверкой границ, скорее всего.

Answer (score -1):

Быстрее всего будет работать массив именно из примитивных типов данных. Большой массив из обьектов лучше тоже делать просто так, ArrayList же - склоняюсь к тому что это разновидность синтактического сахара не предназначенна для больших обьемов. Он при увеличении может вдруг копировать себя, и т.п.
А добавлять в середину ArrayList массива - вообще ересь. Время добавления одного элемента О(н) , в сумме О(н^^2). Для этого надо самому реализовать Linked List, причем ссылки на следующий элемент держать не на элемент типа Object (как делают обычно в Яве)  а на его индекс в массиве (то есть int или другой целый тип), без перемещения самих обьектов Object.
Хух, надеюсь помог))